# Why Resnet model in tensorflow and pytorch give different feature length?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to extract features of images through Resnet models pretrained on imagenet dataset as for the network should give the length of 2048 features. When I experimented with TensorFlow it gave the same amount of feature-length but when I try PyTorch version Resnet it gives me the length of 1000.

codes are as below
for Tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import pickle
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
import os
import random
import time
import math
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D

def model_picker(name):
    if (name == 'vgg16'):
        model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                      include_top=False,
                      input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                      pooling='max')
    elif (name == 'vgg19'):
        model = VGG19(weights='imagenet',
                      include_top=False,
                      input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                      pooling='max')
    elif (name == 'mobilenet'):
        model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet',
                          include_top=False,
                          input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                          pooling='max',
                          depth_multiplier=1,
                          alpha=1)
    elif (name == 'inception'):
        model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',
                            include_top=False,
                            input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                            pooling='max')
    elif (name == 'resnet'):
        model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                         include_top=False,
                         input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                        pooling='max')
    elif (name == 'xception'):
        model = Xception(weights='imagenet',
                         include_top=False,
                         input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                         pooling='max')
    else:
        print("Specified model not available")
    return model


model_architecture = 'resnet'
model = model_picker(model_architecture)

def extract_features(img_path, model):
    input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
    img = image.load_img(img_path,
                         target_size=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1]))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    expanded_img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    preprocessed_img = preprocess_input(expanded_img_array)
    features = model.predict(preprocessed_img)
    flattened_features = features.flatten()
    normalized_features = flattened_features / norm(flattened_features)
    return normalized_features
features = extract_features('dog.jpg', model)
print(len(features))

> 2048
```

As you can see it gives a length of 2048 features through the resnet50 model

Below is the code for PyTorch

```
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch
res_model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
def image_loader(image,model,use_gpu= False):
  transform = transforms.Compose([
                                  transforms.Resize(256),
                                  transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                  transforms.ToTensor()
  ])
  img = Image.open(image)
  img = transform(img)
  print(img.shape)

  x = Variable(torch.unsqueeze(img, dim = 0).float(), requires_grad = False)
  print(x.shape)
  if use_gpu:
    x = x.cuda()
    model = model.cuda()
  y = model(x).cpu()
  print(y.size())
  y = torch.squeeze(y)
  y = y.data.numpy()
  print(y.shape)
  print(len(y))
  np.savetxt('features.txt',y,delimiter=',')
image_loader('dog.jpg',res_model)

> torch.Size([3, 224, 224]) torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224]) torch.Size([1,
> 1000]) (1000,) 1000
```

As you can see it gives a length of 1000 for the feature extracted through the Resnet model with the PyTorch model
why am I getting different lengths isn't I get the same length according to architecture which is 2048 or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Printing the layers of the pytorch resnet will yield:

```
(fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1000, bias=True)
```

as the last layer of the resnet in Pytorch, because the model is by default set up for use as a classifier on imagenet data (1000 classes). If you want 2048 features instead, you can simply delete this last layer.

```
del model.fc
```

and your resulting output will then be of the desired dimension.

Edit: perhaps better is to simply overwrite `model.fc` with an identity function rather than deleting it so it doesn't cause errors when `forward` is called:

```
model.fc = torch.nn.Identity()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that's true but when I run inference after removing the FC layer I get error as  AttributeError: 'ResNet' object has no attribute 'fc'

Comment: Ah, yes, you'd need to remove the reference to `model.fc` in the `forward` function, which would be a bit of a pain because you'd have to overwrite the original `forward` definition. Instead you can just replace the original layer with a dummy layer that does nothing. See edited answer above.